# Third Party App Making SQL Join Query with Table Designs - SQL

Tags: sql

By Joining Several Tables you will get some columns as outputs.

Is there any third party (or SQL add-in) to create join queries on tables by drag and dropping (selecting) columns from tables and It checks and create the query for us?

Comment: which database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are on SQL server there is a query designer as part of SSRS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/query-design-tools-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017